# sql How to apply sum() with different condition in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get sum quantity of A and B in new column named group1 and group 2 have distinct value with Category . And want to get both columns in same execution .

```
c1   |   c2
---------------
A    |   2
B    |   1
A    |   2
B    |   1
A    |   2
B    |   1




result :


group1 | group2
---------------
A      | 6
B      | 3
```

I am trying this query but not working

```
 SELECT SUM(c2) WHERE DISTINCT c1 in('A','B') as 'group2' from table,
    SELECT DISTINCT c1 in('A','B') as 'group1' from table
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a straightforward group by.  Based on your example:

```
SELECT c1 as group1, SUM(c2) as group2 
FROM table
GROUP BY c1
```

Comment: not working , I have tried with table reference also . Can you please put the query in complete syntax ?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  In my example, replace "table" with the name of the table, like `FROM mytable`, where "mytable" is the name of your table